# Serializing an object to XML and appending it to XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization

I'm trying to convert a (horse) object into an XmlElement so that I can append it to an XML file. This is what I've tried most recently.

```
        // create writer and serializer to add horse to xml
        var stringwriter = new StringWriter();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(horse.GetType());

        // serialize horse object to xml 
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, horse);
        var xmlStr = stringwriter.ToString();

        // format string to xml 
        var horseXml = new XmlDocument();
        horseXml.LoadXml(xmlStr);

        // get horse element from horseXml
        var horseEl = horseXml.ChildNodes[0];

        // assign xmldb to xml document
        var xmlDb = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDb.Load(xmlDbFilepath);
        XmlNode root = xmlDb.DocumentElement;

       // add horseEl to root of xmlDb
        root.AppendChild(horseEl);
        xmlDb.Save(xmlDbFilepath);
```

Unfortunately, once I get to the line, root.AppendChild(horseEl), this throws the following exception: "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The node to be inserted is from a different document context."

Any advice would be much appreciated!

EDIT: here's a link showing [my horse class and xmldb](https://gist.github.com/jekrch/f4e5e06fcf23d78f12ef).

Comment: Please include the class definition of `horse` and the content of file `xmlDbFilepath`.

Comment: The class Horse is incomplete. Please add definition of the subclasses and enums.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Sorry about that. I just updated the Gist with the other. I should mention that the xml file was originally created by serializing a List<Horse>. Here's the code that I used for that: `XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(horses.GetType());
            
            var stream = new FileStream(xmlDbFilepath,
                FileMode.Create);
            x.Serialize(stream, horses);
            stream.Close();`

Comment: Have tried the suggestions which you get when you google the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Should work if data and class structure are correct.

```
// same code till this

// get horse element from horseXml
XmlElement horseEl = horseXml.DocumentElement; //[1] get the doc element

// assign xmldb to xml document
var xmlDb = new XmlDocument();
xmlDb.Load(xmlDbFilepath);
//XmlNode root = xmlDb.DocumentElement; [2] removed

// add horseEl to root of xmlDb
//var newRoot = root.AppendChild(clonedHorseEl); [3] removed
var xe = xmlDb.CreateElement("Horse"); //[4] Create new Horse element on xmlDb
xe.InnerXml = horseEl.InnerXml; //[5] copy horseEl content
xmlDb.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xe);

xmlDb.Save(xmlDbFilepath);
```

The changes are mentioned in comments.